# Binding parameters with SQL

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am familiar with binding parameters with SQL within SQLAlchemy. However is it possible to bind not only parameters but also part of the SQL statement? I am talking about something like this.

Let's assume a very simple query like

```
select *
from table
where param1 = 1
and param2 = 2
```

In order to provide this query with parameters, I simply write

```
select *
from table
where param1 = :value1
and param2 = :value2
```

But the question is how can I parameterise the condition "and" so the final query will looks like:

```
select *
from table
where param1 = :value1
:condition param2 = :value2
```

Is it possible with use of SQLAlchemy text() function. To add a bit complexity to the issue the select statement does not refer directly to table but to function that returns not a single value. So the real query should looks like:

```
select *
from function(
    :value_1,
    :value_2,
    :value_3)
where param1 = :value_4
  :condition param2 = :value_5
```

Comment: This is only possible using dynamic SQL.  Keywords cannot be passed in as parameters.

Comment: SQLAlchemy in itself provides a query building DSL: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html